# Displaying iso-8859-1 encoded content in WebView

Tags: android

I am obtaining HTML coded content from an SQlite database that I would like to display in a WebView . I am currently using:

```
public class ShowAbstracts extends Activity {
 public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
 {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
    if (extras != null) {
         String body = extras.getString(DatabaseHelper.KEY_BODY);
         WebView webview = new WebView(this);
         setContentView(webview);
         String summary = "<html><body> "+body+" </body></html>";
         webview.loadData(summary, "text/html", "iso-8859-1");
    }   
 }
}
```

It works in that it opens a WebView and displays the contents but I get strange characters and for some content it just crashes. The Database is ISO-8859-1 encoded.
Is there any way to take care of the special characters in my database content and display them properly?

Thanks very much in advance!

Rik

Comment: try specifying the charset in the html header too.

Answer (score 5):

Success!

Solving this was a combination of 3 things:

1. uri encoding the string
2. pasting a head in the HTML string identifying utf-8 encoding
3. installing LibreOffice which allowed the xls file used for generating the SQLite database to be saved as a csv file with utf-8 encoding (as far as I can tell not possible from MS Office Excel).

.

```
 public class ShowAbstracts extends Activity {
    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
        if (extras != null) {
           String body = extras.getString(DatabaseHelper.KEY_BODY);
           WebView webview = new WebView(this);
           setContentView(webview);
           String summary = "<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?><html><body>"+body+" </body></html>";
           String uri = Uri.encode(summary);
           webview.loadData(uri, "text/html", "utf-8");
        }   
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The api for WebView (http://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebView.html) says that the the data argument must be URI-escaped (http://developer.android.com/reference/java/net/URLEncoder.html).

Also, when you have a string, the encoding has already been done. You have to see to that the string is created using the correct encoding (for Android the default is UTF-8).

Comment: Thanks! Well adding 
      String summary = "<html><body>"+body+" </body></html>";
      String uri = Uri.encode(summary);
      webview.loadData(uri, "text/html", "iso-8859-1");
certainly stopped the crashes but unfortunately I still get funny characters. A simple hyphen(-) is even displayed as ï¿½ ...
I've tried including the charset in the html header and that doesn't seem to work. I've reimported the csv file into an SQlite database using utf-8 encoding but that messes up the è-like characters...

Comment: Do you do all the processing on android? What format is the csv file in from the start?

Comment: The processing is done on windows and the csv file is extracted from a Microsoft Access database. I create the sqlite database using the SQLite Manager add-on in Firefox.