# Android: reading a text file with ISO-8859-1 character encoding in a webview

Tags: android, encoding, webview

The subject says it all.
I've an html file, coded in ISO-8859-1 (encoding checked with Firefox like explained [here](http://codeftw.blogspot.it/2009/07/how-to-find-character-encoding-of-text.html)).

The code reads the file correctly in a String but when I try to show the text in a WebView I get weird charachters in place of à, è,...

I've tried lot of code (except for the good one, I guess). 
The last version is this (after reading [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5975368/displaying-iso-8859-1-encoded-content-in-webview)):

```
try
        {
            InputStreamReader is = new InputStreamReader(getApplicationContext().getAssets().open("file.html"), "ISO-8859-1");
            BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(is);
            String txt = "";
            while ( (result = br.readLine()) != null)
            {
                txt= txt+ result;
            }
            String uri = Uri.encode("<?xml version='1.0' encoding='ISO-8859-1'?>" + txt);
            webView.loadData(uri, "text/html", "ISO-8859-1");
        }
        catch (IOException ex){

        }
```

**SOLUTION**

Ok I'm answering myself. This code works:

```
try
        {
            InputStreamReader is = new InputStreamReader(getApplicationContext().getAssets().open("filelgc2.html"), Charset.forName("ISO-8859-1"));
            BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(is);
            String testo = "";
            while ( (result = br.readLine()) != null)
            {
                testo = testo + result;
            }
            webView.loadData(testo, "text/html; charset=UTF-8", null);
        }
        catch (IOException ex){
        }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok I'm answering myself. This code works:

```
try
        {
            InputStreamReader is = new InputStreamReader(getApplicationContext().getAssets().open("filelgc2.html"), Charset.forName("ISO-8859-1"));
            BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(is);
            String testo = "";
            while ( (result = br.readLine()) != null)
            {
                testo = testo + result;
            }
            webView.loadData(testo, "text/html; charset=UTF-8", null);
        }
        catch (IOException ex){
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to read the `txt` file as `byte[]` then encode it to `String` using `new String(bytes,"ISO-8859-1")` before showing it

Comment: The problem is that this is only a example, in the real program I'll receive the data from a sqlite database. I've the same problem there (the data are ISO-8859-1 encoded).

Comment: And if I inspect the txt variable, data and encoding are correct. The problem comes when I try to show the html page stored in txt in the webview.

Comment: then try to load it using `webView.loadData(testo, "text/html; charset=UTF-8", "ISO-8859-1");`